# Python MySQL IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, mysql

Getting an `IndexError: list index out of range Error`. New to Python, complete beginner and would appreciate some help to understand whats wrong.

Getting json from a timesheet api which i need to save to a mysql database

```
import requests
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json 
import mysql.connector

site = 'https://api.site.com/Projects/?version=5'
hdr = {'Authorization': 'WRAP access_token="TOKEN"', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
try:
     page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
     print e.fp.read()

response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
json_obj = json.loads(response.decode ('utf8'))

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "HOST_IP",
                   user = "USER",
                   passwd = "PASS",
                   db = "DB",
                   port=3306,
                   collation="utf8mb4_unicode_ci")

cursor = conn.cursor ()

for Project in json_obj["Projects"]:
     cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO project 
                (ID, Client_Name, Name, BusSector, ProjCat, SageCode)
            VALUES 
                (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
               Name = VALUES(Client_Name),
               Name = VALUES(Name),
                Name = VALUES(BusSector),
                Name = VALUES(ProjCat),
                Name = VALUES(SageCode);
                       """,(Project["ID"],Project["Client"]["Name"],Project["Name"],Project["CustomFields"][0]["Values"][0],Project["CustomFields"][2]["Values"][0],Project["CustomFields"][1]["Values"][0])     
                      )
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

The output from Traceback is:

```
line 52, in <module>  """,(Project["ID"],Project["Client"]["Name"],Project["Name"],Project["CustomFields"][0]["Values"][0],Project["CustomFields"][2]["Values"][0],Project["CustomFields"][1]["Values"][0])
```

Comment: We can't see your JSON, but it's clear that one of the items you're referencing with `[]` does not exist. (That's the only possible reason for *index out of range* errors in any language.) Inspect your values and make sure they match what you're trying to read with all of those `Project[][][]` references.

Comment: excellent, thanks! Yes, one of the Project[][][] is not completed sometimes, code modified to accept this and apply a null value